# Desktop shortcut doesn't work if use pipe in command

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pipe, shortcut-file

Today I tried to create a desktop shortcut to launch Skype and use pipelogin.

I created the following shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Skype2
Name[en_US]=Skype2
Icon=skype
Exec=echo login password | skype --dbpath=/home/kont/.Skype2 --pipelogin
```

but when I tried to launch it nothing happend. Then I tried to launch Skype without the pipelogin:

```
Exec=echo skype --dbpath=/home/kont/.Skype2
```

and it worked fine. So I decided that the reason is in using pipe `|`. To approve this version I have created the login_skype.sh file with the following code:

```
Exec=echo login password | skype --dbpath=/home/kont/.Skype2 --pipelogin
```

and changed the shortcut so that it launch the login_skype.sh and it also works fine.

Are there any ideas what was wrong in the first shortcut code version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try launching it in a subshell:

```
Exec=sh -c 'echo login password | skype --dbpath=/home/kont/.Skype2 --pipelogin'
```

Comment: this worked for me in xfce on debian bookworm. thanks